# What caused NFS filesystem to be mounted?

Tags: mount, nfs

How do I find which script, configuration file, etc. mounted an NFS filesystem on my Linux server?   I've looked through `/etc/fstab`, but it does not contain any `nfs` line; also I found nothing in `auto.master`.

Comment: Do you mean from which point in time?

Comment: I search conf file or service or some one else which mount share on boot.

Comment: Have you looked in `/etc/rc.local` or any of the other /etc/rc.d files (the ones running after the network comes up) if they do the mounting?

Comment: I try to search
**[root@as21421 /]# grep -rnw /etc -e "/cgg " --devices=skip**
/etc/mtab:17:as21419:/cgg /cgg nfs rw,tcp,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,addr=10.0.0.89 0 0
And it found only one record in mtab. Cant find any mount command
PS /cgg - is dest pount point

Comment: Could it be added in a `cron` file of some user which are seated in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`?

Comment: `showmount`    is the command

Answer (score 1):

If nfs mount does not resides in fstab, means it is a temporary mount (lost after reboot).
You can use df -h to check the mount point, if the first column is a hostname/ip, then it must be an nfs mount.

```
# df -h
...
192.168.1.2:/ora_share   300G   206G    88G    71%    /ora
```

Comment: While `/etc/fstab` is a good place to configure mounts, somebody may have added a special mount into a custom script as @Anthon commented. +1 though because you explain that it might be a temporary mount. Somebody might have mount the export manually and did not configure the `/etc/fstab` (yet).

Comment: mount on my server restore on reboot